# endpoints proto datastore + GeoModel , metaclass conflict

Tags: google-app-engine, endpoints-proto-datastore

I am trying to implement [GeoModel](https://code.google.com/p/geomodel/) with Endpoints proto datastore like this:

```
class Professional(EndpointsModel , GeoModel):
    pass
```

getting:

```
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

I want to be able to use the Endpoints Proto Datastore and be able to search by proximity and such.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

GeoModel is based on the old db.Model, while endpoints-proto-datastore uses the newer ndb.Model. You'll need to re-implement one of them, and converting GeoModel to use ndb is probably the better choice.